# How to define event handler as elements class method?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I tried to define click event handler as elements class method

Why it is not working?

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
    ...
    onclick () {
      console.log(event)
    }
}
```

But it works in this way

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.onclick = console.log
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ES7+ way

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    onclick = () => {...}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
someElm.onclick = console.log
```

where `someElm` is an element, you're actually *invoking a setter* which attaches the listener:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick'));
```

That's why `this.onclick =` works. It's not just a plain assignment - it results in a function call, and that function call is needed for the browser to register the attachment of a listener.

In contrast, having an onclick *method* in the prototype doesn't invoke that setter, so it doesn't tell the browser to add a listener; it simply adds a property to the prototype chain of the instance.

For similar reasons, creating an object with an `onclick` property where the object's *internal prototype* also has an `onclick` setter doesn't invoke the setter:

```js
const theProto = {
  set onclick(newVal) {
    console.log('setter invoked');
  }
};

// Works:
theProto.onclick = 'foo';

console.log('About to create new object, but setter will not be invoked');
const theInstance = Object.create(theProto, { onclick: () => console.log('Onclick in instance running') });
```

Answer (score -1):

> Why it is not working?

See @CertainPerformance's answer.

> How to define event handler as elements class method?

You could use `addEventListener()` as below:

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.addEventListener( 'click', this.onclick )
    }

    onclick( ev ) {
        console.log( ev.target, this )
    }
}

customElements.define( 'c-e', Component )
```

```html
<c-e>Click Me</c-e>
```

Note that it is not really a literal event handler (but I suppose it's what you meant).

If you want a real event handler, you should define a getter and a setter.